# Get only value of item stored in localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get the value from what I saved in localStorage, but I also get the name of the key stored.

```
localStorage.setItem('token', tokenJson);
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')));
```

The console.log returns something like `{"token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjo0LCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InJpY2FyZG8uY2Fycm9sYUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE1MzMxMjc1ODksImVtYWlsIjoicmljYXJkby5jYXJyb2xhQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsIm9yaWdfaWF0IjoxNTMyNTIyNzg5fQ.nYijM4xxFH_Cuoahi-eximAQcQeQ3v1bDRy09ltgDdA"}` but I only want what is after the colon without the quotation marks.
I dont't know if it was clear, but I need the token, only its value to do a fetch to make an API call.

What I want is, when I make the request, the answer to be something like:

`JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjo0LCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InJpY2FyZG8uY2Fycm9sYUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE1MzMxMjc1ODMsImVtYWlsIjoicmljYXJkby5jYXJyb2xhQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsIm9yaWdfaWF0IjoxNTMyNTIyNzgzfQ.NMTLQCalo9UMMtJXUq7ynzpUbL3m3rjumMw9unoZhtc`

and not like this

`JWT {"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjo0LCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InJpY2FyZG8uY2Fycm9sYUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE1MzMxMjc1ODMsImVtYWlsIjoicmljYXJkby5jYXJyb2xhQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsIm9yaWdfaWF0IjoxNTMyNTIyNzgzfQ.NMTLQCalo9UMMtJXUq7ynzpUbL3m3rjumMw9unoZhtc"}`

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')).token`? You could also just store the value of the token and not the entire token object in localStorage if that would make it easier for you.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')).token);` - access the `token` property

Comment: Why store it as json? setItem("token", tokenJson.token) and get it as let token = getItem("token");

Comment: I tried @Tholle but when I tried that it stopped storing correctly and it stored as `[Object Object]`

Comment: Thanks, I already got it thanks to your comments, appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding .token to my getItem I managed to access only the content of whats stored locally. Thanks to the people who helped!

`(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')).token)`

Answer (score 0):

Well then just save the value of the token instead of an object.

```
var tokenJson = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjo0LCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InJpY2FyZG8uY2Fycm9sYUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE1MzMxMjc1ODksImVtYWlsIjoicmljYXJkby5jYXJyb2xhQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsIm9yaWdfaWF0IjoxNTMyNTIyNzg5fQ.nYijM4xxFH_Cuoahi-eximAQcQeQ3v1bDRy09ltgDdA";

localStorage.setItem('token', tokenJson);
console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'));

// eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjo0LCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InJpY2FyZG8uY2Fycm9sYUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE1MzMxMjc1ODksImVtYWlsIjoicmljYXJkby5jYXJyb2xhQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsIm9yaWdfaWF0IjoxNTMyNTIyNzg5fQ.nYijM4xxFH_Cuoahi-eximAQcQeQ3v1bDRy09ltgDdA
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use localStorage.getItem() method directly

Example

```
localStorage.setItem('token','xyz')

console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'))
```